# Is WampServer on Windows vulnerable to Bash Bug / Shell Shock?

Tags: security

The title says it all.  I don't think Wamp is running with Cygwin but I would like to be sure of that.

Comment: For your information, WAMP/XAMPP/etc should **never** be used in production. They are tools for software development only.

Comment: @EEAA Thank's for the info but I already know that.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Can I improve my question or should I delete it?

Comment: Because you are asking a question about a development tool on a systems administration site.

Comment: @EEAA Thanks for the info. I'm sorry : I thought it was legit to ask since there is a WampServer tag.

Comment: Not true - they can be used if they are needed (f.e. customer/boss wants windows system, we want a usable system, WAMP could be a good compromise). Although its performance is not the best, it is not always a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  WAMP out of the box does not use Cygwin, or come bundled with an implementation of bash for that matter.